# Exoplanet Mass-Radius Diagram

Tags: mass, astrophysics, exoplanets

I'm currently studying the following diagram:

[image: Mass-Radius Diagram]

But I'm not entirely sure I understand what's going on. Is it just, that most exoplanets discovered, is pretty much made up of Hydrogen and Helium ? And then a couple (Like around (1,1)) have the composition like the earth i.e. iron and such.

Basically: The place the planet is located, does that just tell me what most of the planet is made of?

And what is the difference between exoplanets and solar system planets? I thought exoplanets was planets orbiting a star. But maybe the solar system planets are planets within a system of many planets orbiting a sun, and exoplanet only one planet around one star?

Comment: Exoplanet means those planets that arent in *our* solar system, and solar system planets are in *our* solar system . the two (blue)triangles must be earth and mars i suppose and purple points are exoplanets and yes most of the exoplanets are made of Hydrogen and helium and revolve around other stars

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense now. Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you :) Make an answer, and I will accept it if you want.

Comment: That diagram is from a [paper that is seven years old](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007ApJ...669.1279S). You might be interested in playing around with [exoplanets.org](http://exoplanets.org), where you can make more up-to-date plots like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q9vz5.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exoplanet means those planets that *arent in our* solar system, and solar system planets *are in our* solar system . The two (blue)triangles must be earth and mars i suppose and purple points are exoplanets and yes most of the exoplanets are made of Hydrogen and helium and revolve around other stars from the graph given .